# How to simplify the Boolean expression $A'BC + AB'C' + A'B'C' + AB'C + AB$?

Tags: boolean-algebra

> How to simplify this Boolean expression?
> $$A'BC + AB'C' + A'B'C' + AB'C + AB$$

I have solved it using Kmap and found the answer to be
$$A + BC + B'C'$$

I tried simplifying it using the rules but only got to
$$B'C' + C (A'B + AB') + AB$$

Seeing that I already have $B'C'$ in my answer, I assume I only need to simplify $C (A'B + AB') + AB$ to $A + BC$, but I don't know how.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write $AB=ABC+ABC’$ and go from there.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}A'BC+AB'C'+A'B'C'+AB'C+AB&=A'(BC+B'C')+A(B'C'+B'C+B)\\
&=A'(BC+B'C')+A(B'(C'+C)+B)\\
&=A'(BC+B'C')+A(B'+B)\\
&=A'(BC+B'C')+A(1)\\
&=A'(BC+B'C')+A(1+BC+B'C')\\
&=A'(BC+B'C')+A+A(BC+B'C')\\
&=(A'+A)(BC+B'C')+A\\
&=A+BC+B'C'\\
\end{align}

Comment: In the 6th line, you do not need $AA’$ because $A’(BC+B’C’)+A(BC+B’C’)=BC+B’C’$

Comment: That is a nice simplification of the proof. Thank you @RezhaAdrianTanuharja.

Comment: Where did the (1 + BC + B'C') come from in the 5th line?

Comment: @pi3.14 $A$ is the same as $A$ AND $1$. Also; $1$ is the same as $1$ OR something else. So $A$ must be the same as $A$ AND ($1$ OR something else). Is that helpful?

Comment: @user400188 yes, it is! Thank you so much!